# How to Attach Image into Mail Function Without HTML Form

Tags: php

I have a very simple code like this

```
<?php
$to = "somobe@yahoo.ca";
$subject = "I am sending an image";
$txt = "Get the Image";
$headers = "From: someone else";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

can you please let me know how I can attach an image to that? For example let say I have an image in `img` folder called `test.png`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the PHPmailer script, is the better way, wp_mail is even more easy but that´s another subject, here is a post that will solve your problem.

[Send attachments with PHP Mail()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail)

using wp_mail would be something as easy as this:

```
<?php
$to = "somobe@yahoo.ca";
$subject = "I am sending an image";
$txt = "Body of the message (can be a html or text/plain)";
$headers = "From: someone else";
$attachment= "image.jpg";// just like this in the root folder of your script, if you have your image in another folder then just write the path.
wp_mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers,$attachment);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to request the image through http

```
<img src="http://www.yourdomain.com/img/test.png">
```